# Characterization of function with $n$-th derivative bounded by $n!$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functions, exponential-function, estimation

Given a $f \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (the set of smooth functions that vanishes at infinity) is in general false that its derivative are bounded, also if the function is bounded (see e.g. $f(x)=\frac{\sin(e^x-1)}{x}$).

For polynomial we know that $P_n^{(n)}(x)=Cn!$ where $C$ is a constant. There is some similar estimation for some subclass of $C^\infty_0$ functions i.e. is it possible to characterize in some way the functions such that for any $n > N_0$
$$
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}f^{(n)}(x) \le n! M^n
$$
where $N_0$ and $M$ are constants?

EDIT:

the function
$
f(x):= e^{-|x|^2} 
$
satisfies all the conditions so not only the polynomial satisfies this inequality. Is it true also for all the compactly supported functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I think $e^{-|x|^2}$ satisfies this

Comment: A compactly supported function cannot satisfy this condition. Any function satisfying this has convergent Taylor expansion at every point ($|\sum f^{(n)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^n/n!| \le \sum (M|x-x_0|)^n = \frac1{1-M|x-x_0|}$). Such functions are probably only in a [Gevrey class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gevrey_class)

Comment: I think any such function is necessary analytical - Taylor series converges with radius at least $1 / M$, and reminder in Lagrange form goes to zero there as well, so function is the same as sum of it's Taylors series on every ball $B_{1/M}(x)$.

Comment: @mihaild the function 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{|x|^2}}}{|x|^2} \text{ if} x \ne 0\\ 0 \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
satisfies the condition, but it isn't analytical near zero

Comment: @CalvinKhor as written in the page you linked, $\sigma = 1$ indeed gives analytical functions (it also has less strict restrictions than this question, because it allows $M$ to depend on compact, while this question requires it to be the same for entire $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: @mihaild Yes agreed. I guess for completeness my earlier comment should also mention that the identity theorem is also valid for real functions, which is why compactly supported functions are not (real) analytic

Comment: @Marco, the condition implies analytic at zero (see my second comment or mihaild's first comment)

Comment: @CalvinKhor But the function that i have posted (in the case of $\mathbb{R}$) has derivatives 
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{P_n(x)}{x^{3n+2}}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}
$$
where $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial, but it is not analytical near zero (the limit of the derivatives is identically  zero)

Comment: @Marco $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$, but $f^{(n)}(x) \cdot n!$ is not uniformly bounded.

Comment: @mihaild
you're right, but $\sup(f^{(n)}(x)) \le M_n$ where $M_n$ is a sequence that diverges as $O(x^{3n+2})$ at most. doesn't this imply that, for $n$ big enough the estimation holds?
(My question ask for $\frac{\sup(f^{(n)}(x))}{n!} \le M^n$, not for the multiplication)

Comment: And my comment should have also been division, not multiplication ($f^{(n)}(x) < M / n!$ is very restrictive). How did you got your estimation on $M_n$? In addition to denominator, we also have increasing coefficients in numerator.

Comment: @mihald
The numerator is a polynomial of degree $2n$ multiplied by a function that is bounded by 1  while the denominator is the term $x^{3n+2}$

So any derivative is bounded by a sequence that goes to infinity as a poly $x^{5n+2}$ at most, but still less than a factorial
NVM. the coefficients actually increases as $(n+1)!$ , so it diverges

Comment: As a side note, Fourier transform of any smooth function with compact support has this property (and even stronger, $|f^{(n)}(x)| < M^{n + 1}$).